# How do you store an entire array into another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do you store an entire array into another array

suppose I have an array

```
data = np.array([], dtype=float, ndmin=2)
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
```

How do you store the values such that

```
data = [ [1,2,3],
         [4,5,6] ]
```

My current method is

```
data= np.append(data, a)
data= np.append(data, b)
```

However this results in [ 1,2,3,4,6]

Comment: Do you happen to know the number of such arrays that you need to append beforehand?

Comment: @Divakar I need to append 1000 arrays of size 70L

Comment: Then, you can initialize the data array : `data = np.empty((1000,70), dtype=float)` and then at each iteration, just index and set elems : `data[i] = a`, `data[i] = b` and so on, where `i` is the iterator. This should be much more efficient than iterative appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like:

```
>>> data = np.array([a,b])
>>> data
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

If you want to do it stepwise, you *can* use append, but you need to make sure all your arguments are rank 2 (or wrapped in a list). Right now, `a` and `b` are both rank 1 so if you try to append along a particular axis, you'll get an error. I.e. what you need to do is:

```
>>> data = np.empty([0,3]); data
array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)

>>> data = np.append(data, np.array([a]), axis=0); data
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.]])

>>> data = np.append(data, np.array([b]), axis=0); data
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```

---

PS. However, if the number of rows in `data` are known (say, 100), you're probably better off preallocating, i.e. initializing it as `np.empty([100,3])` and filling by index, (e.g. `data[0,:] = a`)

Comment: What if I want to do a for loop appending multiple arrays?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the stepwise approach too.

Answer (score 3):

So you are looking for `np.vstack`:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
data = np.vstack([a,b])
```

Comment: What if I want to do a for loop appending multiple arrays?

Comment: first generate a list, then concatenate the list to one array.

Comment: or just do `data = np.vstack([data,a])` at each iteration

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: that scales not very well, since you have to copy each time all data to a new array.

Comment: yes agreed. it's best to preallocate. but having said that, generating a list iteratively and concatenating at the end isn't going to be much better either.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but, this is only efficient if you already have a list of arrays, right? OP seems to be interested in doing this iteratively, so presumably he/she's generating them on the spot. All I'm saying is if you're generating them inside a for loop and retaining them somewhere in memory, then whether you collect them as a list or as a numpy array directly makes no difference, right? But if you know the exact number of rows, you might as well preallocate data and assign by index, which will be much more efficient as you dont need to keep allocating new memory to expand a list.

Comment: Creating a list is much more efficient, than creating a new array each time.